# Unsigned integer datatype in column-oriented DBMS

Tags: database, types, column-oriented, unsigned-integer

I have checked different column-oriented database systems such as InfiniDB, InfobrightDB and MonetDB. None of them support unsigned integers as a data storage type. Why? One solution is to store all 4 byte unsigned integers into 8 byte signed integers ([Link](http://www.infobright.org/images/uploads/blogs/how-to/How_To_Work_With_Data_Types_in_Infobright.pdf)), however I think it would waste too much space. Is there any open-source column oriented database system that support unsigned integers? I already checked this ([Link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Column-oriented_DBMS)) with no luck.
Thank you very much for your time.

Emer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found one answer on the "How to Migrate from SQL Server" ([page4](http://www.infobright.org/images/uploads/blogs/how-to/How_To_Migrate_from_SQL_Server.pdf)) at Infobright.org:

> UNSIGNED INTEGERS – Unsigned integers
>   have historically been selected by
>   DBAs and database designers to provide
>   capacity for larger maximum values for
>   a given integer field than is possible
>   with a signed integer. Where negative
>   values do not exist in the data, or
>   are not allowed, the approach of
>   selecting unsigned integers allowed
>   accommodation of larger values while
>   selecting smaller data types in
>   traditional row-oriented technologies.
>   In Infobright’s case, when unneeded
>   bytes exist for a particular integer
>   value, they are “squeezed” out by the
>   inherent compression algorithms. For
>   this reason, Infobright recommends
>   selecting the next-larger integer data
>   type – for example, BIGINT over
>   INTEGER, or MEDIUMINT over SMALLINT –
>   such that the maximum column value can
>   still be accommodated in the chosen
>   data type. Infobright doesn’t suffer
>   the wasted space consequences of
>   “over- typing” one’s columns.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL supports unsigned integers as a column type

Comment: MySQL is not a column-oriented DB, so it does not apply to the question.